# SMTP email on asp .net

Tags: asp.net, smtp

I have bellow code which is unable to send email to any email address always it returns me false results this code works before and stop working when we change web server do i need to install any extra software..

```
public  bool sendEmail(string to,string from,string message,string subject,string reply_to,string cc)
    {
        MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        MailAddress mAdd = new MailAddress(from);
        MailAddress mAddTo = new MailAddress(to);
        System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        nc.UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerID"].ToString(); 
        nc.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerPASS"].ToString();       
      if (reply_to != "")
        {
            MailAddress mAddRTo = new MailAddress(reply_to);
            msgMail.ReplyTo = mAddRTo;
        }
      if(cc!="")
          msgMail.CC.Add(cc);

         // msgMail.Headers.Add("Date ", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        msgMail.To.Add(mAddTo);
        msgMail.From = mAdd;
        msgMail.Subject = subject;

        msgMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msgMail.Body =message;

        smtpClient.Host = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"].ToString();
        smtpClient.Credentials = nc;
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(msgMail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My web.config smtp configuration;

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MailServer" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <add key="MailServerID" value="abcd@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="MailServerPASS" value="XXXXXXX"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: what is the exception/innerException you are receiving?

Comment: Gmail default use SSL. Add this `smtpClient.EnableSsl=true;`

Comment: I have make these changes in my file and still not receiving email.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the smtp service of gmail.
This service requires authentication, the SSL enabled and a specific port.
Add these lines

```
 smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
 smtpClient.Port = 587;
```

However I am a bit perplexed from your sentence.

> stop working when we change web server

Your code should never have worked

Comment: `stop working when we change web server` I have changed my hosting server and facing this issue in my new server.

I have make these changes in my file and still not receiving email.

Comment: Then you should asking them (the hosting provider administrators) if there is a block for sending emails. However, I am sure that the two lines above are required for smtp.gmail.com

Comment: @HuzoorBux **Medium Trust** is the common setting for ASP.Net on shared environments. If so, you can **only use port 25** for SMTP. So if you changed servers, this is something you need to ask your hosting provider. If you are on a shared server, this is likely.